# Mongo changeStream for a find query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, changestream

I want to make a query on mongo collection and when the collection changes I want to run the query again. But to optimize it, I don't want to run the query on every collection change, only when documents matching the query changes.  I have following code:

```js
const query = { author: someUserID };
const fetch = async () => await collection.find(query).toArray();
const watcher = collection
        .watch([{ $match: { fullDocument: query } }])
        .on("change", () => fetch().then(sendData)); // This does not work
fetch().then(sendData); // This works
```

On first run it fetches documents and executes `sendData` but when new document is inserted, the event is not triggered. When I wun `collection.watch()` without arguments, it works.

Where is the problem?
Thanks.

EDIT: I want to be able to reuse the `query` for `.find()` and for `.watch()`.

Answer (score 1):

The `$match` stage in that example is essentially

```
{$match: { fullDocument: { author: someUserId }}}
```

That will match *only* if the `fullDocument` is exactly `{ author: someUserId }` with no other fields or values.

In order to match the author while permitting other fields in the document, use dotted notation, like

```
const query = { "fullDocument.author": someUserId };
```

and match like:

```
{$match: query }
```

Comment: This way I wouldn't be able to reuse the query for `.find()` and for `.watch()`. I'll update the question.